# Is it recommended to convert Arraylist into Reactor's flux for Processing data?

Tags: java, reactive-programming, flux, project-reactor, reactor

One of my colleagues said to me that instead of processing streams i should create a Flux instead of using a List as it is and then Process my data to it.

But this doesn't makes sense to me because i thought reactive streams were generally useful for blocking io not data processing .

Can someone verify if the new approach suggested by my colleague is correct.
and if it is correct, what are the advantages of it over my previous method(performance wise)

```
//Model
rootObject{
List<rootNodes> rootNodes
}

//My current code 
MonoOfRootObject.map( rootobject.getrootnodes.stream()
.(..do some filtering and replacement..) )


//Proposed code according to my colleague
MonoOfRootObject.map( Flux.fromIterable(rootobject.getrootnodes)
.(..do some filtering and replacement..) )
```

Please help i am a bit new to Reactor (or functional programming in general)

Thanks

Comment: Have you verified the approach by yourself ? maybe it would clarify your doubts

Comment: If your current code really does just map over a list, then both of your approaches are a bit odd and there's no reason to wrap it in a mono at all - just "rootObject.stream()" the list and use the standard Java streams to do the job.

Comment: @Micheal Berry I can only receive root object as a mono and i am not actually converting it to Mono myself, i receive the root object Mono from a reactive repository. I will update the code to be appropriate. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you're right. Reactor and Reactive Streams in general are useful when you need to deal with asynchronous data and/or concurrency.

To do regular filtering, transformation on an in-memory list, Java Stream is totally fine and using Reactive Stream is overkill (and probably also overhead performance wise).